# why is lower added to the hibernate query during like search

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do a like search using Hibernate Criteria.

```
Criterion nameCriteria = Restrictions.ilike("name", fileNameWOE,MatchMode.START);
criteria.add(fileNameCriteria);
List<Account> results = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

But when the hibernate query is generated, it is adding a lower condition to the query.

```
  select
        this_.ID as ID3_0_,
        this_.SESSION_ID as SESSION2_3_0_,
        this_.NAME as NAME3_3_0_,
    from
        account this_ 
    where
        lower(this_.NAME) like ?
```

Is there any reason why hibernate is adding the lower condition automatically and how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Restrictions.ilike` - is a case insensitive search. The usual way to do case-insensitive query is to convert input and db values to same case (using upper or lower). That is the reason why lower is applied to your predicate.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used Restrictions.ilike for a long time but never observed it. I changed it to Restrictions.like and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html):

**[Ilike](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))**

> A case-insensitive "like", similar to Postgres ilike operator

It converts the parameter to lower to make the search case insensitive

If you wanted the same function but not case insensitive you would just use Restrictions.[like](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))